# How to convert time output from SQL*Plus TIMING to a Linux TIMESTAMP?

Tags: bash, time, timestamp, sqlplus

I'm getting a TIMING result from SQL*Plus query like this:

```
00:00:02.02
```

Explaining the construction of this line:

```
hours:minutes:seconds.hundredths
```

For my needs I need to convert it to a Linux timestamp (or just a number containing the SQL*Plus string converted to miliseconds or sth).

I need it to be converted in whole, even with hours.

Comment: `date -d '00:00:00.02' +%s` though date doesn't seem to understand "hundredths".

Comment: @EtanReisner it seems that `date` works fine with my input when writing sth like this: `date -d '00:00:02.02' +%s%N` - but the output looks strange: `1416956402020000000` - every time I'm running this command all the results are not zeros with just my seconds added, but even running this command like `date -d '00:00:00.00' +%s%N` gives the output like `1416956400000000000`. Where is this `14169564` coming from?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was somewhat incomplete. That's the epoch timestamp for that time. Subtract the epoch (`date -d 0 +%s`) from that and you get just the time that took.